# adding data type to fetch response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

```
interface IUsers {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export const fetchUsers = () =>
  fetch(`/users`).then((res) => res.json());
```

How do I add IUsers type to fetchUsers response? fetchUsers return `[{id:1, name:'fay'}].`

Comment: do you mean : `fetchUser = () : iUsers => { // your logic }` ?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar the data is an array of object

Comment: then do you mean :  `fetch(\`/users\`).then((res) => res.json() as iUsers );`?

Comment: but I can't do that, I got `Conversion of type 'Promise<any>' to type 'IUsers' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`

Comment: can you please edit the question with the sample of result of `res.json()` and what you expect as the final output?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar done

Comment: added the answer, pls accept it or let me know for corrections 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have already written this:

```
export interface iUsers {
    id : number
    name : string
}
```

Modify your method like this:

```
export const fetchUsers = async () : Promise<{ data : iUsers[] }>  => {
    const response = await fetch(`/users`) ;
    const data : iUsers[]= await response.json() 
    return { data  }
  }
```

And use it like this :

```
const { data } = await fetchUsers();
```

You can hover on your IDE for the hints, it will show that `data` is an `iUsers[]`

**EDIT**
This is the shorted version you wanted, which might not match your requirements

```
export const fetchUsers = async () : Promise<iUsers[] >  => await (await fetch(`/users`)).json() ;
```

and use it like this :

```
const data = await fetchUsers()
```

Comment: it worked! so you can't use destructing with typescript?

Comment: you can use it - in fact, that's what i've done here, it's just that you required the result to be in this way, i manipulated it to be so

Comment: I mean if it's `const { data: PutMyTypeHere } = 'something'` is not possible right

Comment: How can you reduce 3 lines of your code above in a function to lesser line? you can't right?

Comment: I could, it might look uglier, and not match your requirements, let me edit and add that

Comment: i added it, but i would prefer the previous one... a good developer writes code for the next developer, not for themselves 

Comment: ok I don't get the double await part, the previous version is better

Comment: exactly, readability is more important 